# Best algo for finding no. of steps required to convert a sequence to a palindromic sequence

Tags: palindrome, sequences

[My first question of StackoverFlow, so, HI!]

I'm not sure of what the rules are around the place, but I have a straightforward question as follows...

> The sequences 23, 45, 23 and 23, 45, 56, 23, 23, 56, 45, 23 are
>   examples of palindromes. The sequence 23, 45, 56 is not a palindrome.
>   The sequence 23, 32 is not a palindrome either. A sequence of length 1
>   is always a palindrome. A given sequence of integers can be broken up
>   into parts such that each of them is a palindrome. Consider the
>   sequence 34,45,34,56,34. This can be broken up into 3 palindrome
>   sequences with 34, 45, 34 constituting the first, 56 constituting the
>   second and 34 constituting the third. It can also be broken in 5
>   palindrome sequences each containing a single number.
>
> We want to determine the smallest number K such that the given
>   sequence can be broken up into K palindrome sequences.

Comment: Why the downvote ? I think this is a perfectly well framed question...

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted , but it might be because it violated the conduct of ZCO challenge which was active on codechef(it is active even now )

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int num[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>num[i];
    int c[n];
    int co=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(num[i]!=-1){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;++j){
            if(num[i]==num[j]){
                num[i]=num[j]=-1;
                c[co]=j;
                co++;
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    if(n-co*2==0){
        cout<<1;
    }
    else{
        cout<<n-co*2;
    }

}
```